# Perfect gas relationship between pressure and density

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, gas

I've been given the following equation for a perfect gas:

\begin{equation}
p = k \rho^\gamma
\end{equation}

Where $k$ and $\gamma$ are constants. I'm trying to find out where this comes from or a source for it but I've had no luck. I've looked up different definitions of ideal gases & perfect gases but I can't seem to derive this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an adiabatic process and an ideal gas, then it can be shown that (see [Why is $PV^\gamma$ constant in an adiabatic process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/328281/why-is-pv-gamma-constant-in-an-adiabatic-process) )
$$ pV^{\gamma} = {\rm constant},$$
where $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats $c_p/c_v$.

If we consider a fixed mass of gas, then $V \propto \rho^{-1}$ and so
$$ p = k \rho^{\gamma}$$